# Написать программу, которая находит сумму чисел кратных 3 от 100 до 200

Tags: python

Написать программу, которая находит сумму чисел кратных 3 от 100 до 200

Answer (score 1):

Э - ле - мен - тар - но :

```
print(4848)
```